# How to create an error message when users enter incorrect inputs on registration or form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have two forms on my rails app that require a user to enter a code to confirm that they belong to a school and in the other form a code for a classroom. Every time a user enters or leaves the code blank I get this error message:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

It's always in the create method of the controller so I must not have the correct syntax.

Here are the two controllers where the error occurs.

Registration Controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create

  def update 
    super
  end

  def new
    super
  end

def create
    code = params[:user][:code]
    @school = School.where(:code => code).first

    unless @school
      flash[:error] = "School code not valid"
      render :new
    end

    params[:user][:school_id] =  @school.id
    super
  end
```

School controller

```
def create_teacher
  authorize @school
  params[:user][:school_id] = @school.id
  params[:user][:role] = "teacher"
  @teacher = User.create(teacher_params)

  if @teacher.id.nil?
    flash[:error] = @teacher.errors.full_messages
    render :new_teacher
  else
    respond_with @school
  end
end
```

How do I correct this issue so that it renders a flash error message?

EDIT Screen Shots of actual error. Note, they are both in the create method so I think it's an identical problem.
[image: Registration#Create error]

[image: Pin#Create error]

EDIT: Registration form for adding users to schools.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1>Sign up</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-body">
    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>
       <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :school_code %>
        <%# f.text_field :code, class: "form-control" %>
        <input type="text" id="code" name="user[code]" value>

      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <strong>Student</strong> <%= f.radio_button(:role, "user") %> 
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
      </div>



    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-footer">
    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message including the file name and line number.

Comment: Ok I've added screen shots of the error message

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with your `<%= form_for .. %>` I can get the same error if I enter an invalid argument for that. For the school one try `<%= form_for @school %>` And make sure your new method in your controller (whichever one is rendering the page with the form) is making a new instance of the object,

`def new
   @school = School.new
 end`

And the same with the pin

---

Something like this may be what you're looking for

```
before_action :check_code,     only: :create
...
def check_code
  unless School.find_by school_code params[:school_code]
    flash[:error] = "Invalid school code"
    redirect_to new_reg_path
  end
end
```

And to show the flash message

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>">
    <%= message %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I create new schools in Active admin currently, and then register new users through the registration controller which inherits from deviseregistration controller. The code is meant to tie student users to the appropriate school. I'll post the entire form if you like. The registration works when you type the correct school code. The problem is if you type the wrong code or code is nil.. Do you still think it has to do with @school? I'll post the form now. EDIT: So the form's not actually creating a new school.. just a new user that belongs to a school.

Comment: Ah so it only fails if they enter wrong information on the previous page? You can check validity with AJAX on that page, or do a `before_action :check_code only: create` where check_code is a method that sees if you have a valid code, and redirects to the previous page if not. You could also pass a `flash[:error] = "Invalid school code"`

Comment: Actually thinking about it more, the error suggests that your form argument is the problem, since you are rendering rather than redirecting your `resource` may not be getting created in the create method, only in the new method.